# What's this coarse, dark green grass in my lawn?

Tags: lawn-repair

I've got patches of thick, dark green, coarse grass with stems. Any idea what sort of grass this is, and whether it's worth trying to remove?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tall fescue

it's hard to get rid of.